# Capistrano::ConnectionError , SocketError: getaddrinfo - on cap deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, amazon-ec2, capistrano

Trying to make 'FILTER=app cap deploy', but getting this error.
It raises on one notebook, but another deploys successfully.

What it could be?

options: os-x, rails, mongo, ec2, rubber.

```
[deploy:update_code] exception while rolling back: Capistrano::ConnectionError, connection failed for: app.uncoverage.com (SocketError: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) connection failed for: app.uncoverage.com (SocketError: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) Vyacheslavs-MacBook-Air:uncoverage vekozlov$ git reset --hard HEAD
```

UPD
I added hosts to /etc/hosts and it works fine.

Comment: Please verify work of your DNS: `nslookup app.uncoverage.com`

Comment: thanks, i've solved this problem - in our case i had to add this host to /etc/hosts.

Comment: Has my answer been helpful?

Comment: An interesting reference [Mike Subelsky's fix to the problem.](http://www.subelsky.com/2014/05/fixing-socketerror-getaddrinfo-name-or.html)

Answer (score 5):

This could sounds really stupid, but in my case it was a blank space at the end ip like:

`sever 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx '`

Comment: Thank, You! It was my case :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two main reasons in getting the exception `SocketError: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`. The first is the loss connection, or invalid connection setup to DNS resolver, and the second invalid settings of current DNS. Please make sure that `nslookup app.uncoverage.com` command correctly resolves the specified URI by verifying that the DNS is accessible and gives correct IP.